# How to get classification probabilities when running glmnet

Tags: caret

I am trying to figure out how to get class probabilitis when running a classification using glmnet. I have built the model and done predictions. But all I have is a huge matrix which I don't really know what to do with. Page 14 of http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper talks about something similar but the `extractProb` functions want my `Y` values. It shouldn't need it to do what I want and there is no reason to assume I have them. I mean those are what I want to predict! So, I get the feeling that is not what I want to do.

If I try without giving any `Y`-value I get:

```
extractProb(netFit$finalModel, posTestSet[,-ncol(posTestSet)])
    Error in x$method : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: glmnet is _not_ a classification method.  And use the correct terminology: you are not seeking classification probabilities but rather event probabilities (risks).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use the `finalModel` object. Doing this will avoid any other operations that `train` uses, such as pre-processing. use

```
extractProb(list(netFit), testX = whatever, testY = something)
```

Max

Comment: Interesting, now I get predictions but the number of predictions is all wrong. It seems I get for the training set not the test set that I am giving to the function. I only gave it testX and not testY though. But what I wanted to do was to get predictions for a test set not for the dataset that I used in training...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the function I was looking for was indeed `extractProb` but the parameter was not `testX` but instead `unkX` as in unknown `X`. It is used for giving `X` values with no known `Y` values and predict for them:

```
probabilities <- extractProb(list(netFit), unkX = myX)[,1]
```